# R Plotly multi line plot x axis label

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have a very specific question that relates to multi-line plotly plots in R. I found many questions that relate to bar charts, but nothing close to my current situation.
I have the following simplified dataframe and code:

```
df <- data.frame(SEC_LABEL = c("3M","5Y",'10Y'), SEC1_VALUES = c(1.1, 1.4, 1.6), SEC2_VALUES = c(2.3, 2.6, 3.1), SORT=c(1,2,3))
color_line1 <- "#66C2A5"  #('rgb(102, 194, 165)')
  color_line2 <- "#8DA0CB" #('rgb(110, 194, 165)')

unique_line_names_1 <- "line1"
unique_line_names_2 <- "line2"

x_label < - as.character(df$SEC_LABEL)

p <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~SORT) %>%
      # Time series chart
      add_lines(y = ~SEC1_VALUES, line = list(color = color_line1, width = 3),
                hoverinfo = unique_line_names_1, text = unique_line_names_1, name = unique_line_names_1)  %>%

      add_lines(y = ~SEC2_VALUES, line = list(color = color_line2, width = 3),
                hoverinfo = unique_line_names_2, text = unique_line_names_2, name = unique_line_names_2) %>%

      layout(title=paste0("Curves"),
             showlegend = TRUE,
             margin = list(l=30, r = 20, b = 30, t = 30, pad =1),
             legend = list(x = 0, y = 0.1, 
                           font = list(size = 8),
                           #orientation = 'h',
                           bgcolor ='transparent' ),
             xaxis=list(title='',
                        showline = FALSE,
                        zeroline = FALSE,
                        showticklabels = T,
                        showgrid = FALSE,
                        ticktext = x_label, 
                        gridwidth =0
                        #gridcolor = toRGB("gray50")
                        ),
             yaxis=list(title='',
                        showline = F,
                        zeroline = FALSE,
                        showgrid = T,
                        gridwidth =2)
             )
```

For some reasons the ticks on the x-axis are not re-labeled using the values in vector 'x_label'.
(By the way, the only reason why I use as x-axis the SORT column instead of the SEC_LABEL column is because otherwise the x-axis get alphabetically sorted. Ideally, the desired ordering should be: 3M, 5Y, 10Y, but after having spent two hours, I realized I couldn't fix it).
Thanks for the help

Comment: Simply convert `SEC_LABEL` to a ordered factor, i.e. `df$SEC_LABEL <- factor(df$SEC_LABEL, levels = x_label)` and map it on x. Worked fine.

Comment: @stefan thank you so much!!!!! that's absolutely perfect

Comment: My pleasure. But now I'm wondering myself why your approach has not worked. Hm. Something to think about. (;

Comment: @stefan do you mean it could potentially be a bug?

Comment: Hi @Angelo. Had a look in the specs. So. No it's not a bug. Sometimes plotly isn't that easy or intuitive as ggplot2. As the answer it is a bit lengthy I posted it as an answer. Best S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A I already mentioned in my comment the simple solution is to use an ordered factor, i.e.

```
df$SEC_LABEL <- factor(df$SEC_LABEL, levels = x_label)
```

and map `SEC_LABEL` on x. This way you get a categorical axis with categories in the wanted order.

However, I had a look in the plotly docs using `schema()`. According the specs of plotly `ticktext`

> Sets the text displayed at the ticks position via `tickvals`. Only has
>   an effect if `tickmode` is set to *array*. Used with `tickvals`.

Hence to get your approach to work you have to set the `tickmode` to `"array"` in `layout` and also set the `tickvals`, i.e to `c(1, 2, 3)` in your case. After these adjustments your approach will also work.

Comment: amazing explaination Stefan. Thank you